# Can't get around cloudflare using 2captcha

Tags: cloudflare, captcha, 2captcha

I'm trying to bypass cloudflare using 2captcha but nothing works, the site gives an ERROR_CAPTCHA_UNSOLVABLE error. I suspect the problem is with the site key, because it's the same on all cloudflare sites I've checked. Here it is 0x4AAAAAAADnPIDROrmt1Wwj. Also to clarify that the captcha demo on 2captcha is solved without problems.

```
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from config import API_KEY

solver = TwoCaptcha(API_KEY)
url = 'https://nowsecure.nl'
sitekey = '0x4AAAAAAADnPIDROrmt1Wwj'
ua = UserAgent()


def solve(url, sitekey):
    try:
        result = solver.turnstile(sitekey=sitekey,
                                  url=url,
                                  action='challenge',
                                  data='foo',
                                  pagedata='bar',
                                  useragent=f'{ua.random}'
                                  )
    except:
        print('Failed to solve Captcha')
        exit()
    return result


print(solve(url, sitekey))
```

Please help to understand or if you know any other way to bypass cloudflare I would be grateful for a hint.